# Push notification launches app automatically

Tags: android, push-notification

My application was minimized and if i received any push notification, application automatically launching. This problem not appearing while closing the application using back button. Please provide me some solution/suggestion how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would have registered a receiver for getting push notifications .I assume your are unregistering your receiver in onDestroy. You got to unregister it in onPause so that your receiver is not invoked when the app is not in background. 
Also add your code in your question.

Comment: sorry.. i am not getting what u r trying to explain :(

Comment: check if you unregistering the receiver in onDestroy() method of your activity